# Issue using :after selector to display icon in conjunction with slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

I am building out a mobile navigation menu and I am applying an icon to `li` elements which contain children(a dropdown arrow). I am applying the icon using the `:after` pseudo selector. The issue is that when I use slideToggle to open/close the menu, the arrow icons appear before the menu has slid into place. Is there any way to prevent this or will I have to use a different approach?

```
#navbar li.has-child > a:after {
            color: red;
            content: ' ▸';
            display:inline-block;
            position:absolute;
            right:30px;
        }
            #navbar li.has-child > a.open:after {
                content: ' ▾';
            }
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0y8q360/) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `absolute` position and you haven't define the relative parent for those elements, they are outside of the flow of the `ul` and then doesn't care the overflow hidden of the toggle. Try making the `a` relatives:

```
#navbar > li a {
    position:relative;
}
```

#### [UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0y8q360/1/)

Comment: Glad to help U understand mate @APAD1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way but you can apply such style:

```
#navbar[style*="overflow"] a:after {
   display:none!important;
}
```